# Filter queryset by field with multiple options

Tags: python, django

Having some abstract model with field `date`:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(null=True)
    ...
```

How do I compose a filter query that returns all records where `date` field is either `Null` or is in range of given dates?

This is what I've tried so far but I'm always getting empty queryset:

```
_ = MyModel.objects.filter(Q(date__isnull=True) & Q(date__range=[...])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a logical *or* here, not an *and*, so with `|` instead of `&`:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(Q(date__isnull=True) | Q(date__range=[…])
```

or you can simplify this to:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(Q(date=None) | Q(date__range=[…])
```

By using a logical and, you want to retrieve `MyModel`s where the `data`-field is *both* `NULL` and in the range of `…` for the *same* record. No value is NULL and in the range at the same time.